# How to plot the running average of my graph and calculate average value (±) using python

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have a file (**file.xvg**), of which I plot the result using matplotlib and numpy (version Python 3.9.12).
here my script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

x, y = numpy.loadtxt("file.xvg", unpack=True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(13,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x, y, color="k", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.8)

ax.set_xlabel("Times (ps)", fontweight='bold', fontsize = 18, labelpad=3)
ax.set_ylabel("Pressures (bar)", fontweight='bold', fontsize = 18, labelpad=3)

plt.show()
```

and the file.xvg

> ```
>    0.0000000    0.0287198
>    0.0100000    0.0655187
>    0.0200000    0.0665948
>    0.0300000    0.0676697
>    0.0400000    0.0797021
>    0.0500000    0.0883750
>    0.0600000    0.0824649
>    0.0700000    0.0726798
>    0.0800000    0.0749663
>    0.0900000    0.0746549
>    0.1000000    0.0767466
>    0.1100000    0.1051620
>    0.1200000    0.0846607
>    0.1300000    0.0746683
>    0.1400000    0.0744862
>    0.1500000    0.0913541
>    0.1600000    0.0844304
>    0.1700000    0.0750595
>    0.1800000    0.0783450
>    0.1900000    0.0869718
>    0.2000000    0.0969575
>    0.2100000    0.0924280
>    0.2200000    0.0759971
>    0.2300000    0.0704025
> .
> .
> .
> ```

I wanted to plot the running average as in the figure below:
[image]

The average value of the plot figure is **7.5 ± 160.5 bar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to calculate your running avg (selecting a window of values `rang`) for both your `x` and `y` array:

```
x_avg = []
y_avg = []
rang = 10
for ind in range(len(y)-rang +1):
    y_avg.append(np.mean(y[ind:ind+rang]))
    x_avg.append(np.mean(x[ind:ind+rang]))

ax.plot(x_avg, r_avg, color="red", linestyle='solid', linewidth=0.8)
```

PS: what a throwback, is that GROMACS? :)

Comment: Thanks imburningbabe, I can see the result.

Comment: But can I also calculate the average value of PLOT ???

Comment: I didn't understand the answer. What do you mean with average of plot?

Comment: I wanted to calculate the average value,
for example of the example illustrated in figure, the average value is 7.5 ± 160.5 bar

Comment: You can calculate the mean as `y.mean()` and the standard error as the ratio between the standard deviation and the root of the number of samples, `np.std(y)/ np.sqrt(len(y))`

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much dear imburningbabe. knowing that I am beginner with python
I did not understand well, do I have to calculate the average of the second column (Y axis) ???

Comment: Yes, I think the mean you are looking for is the mean over all your data, that are stored in the y variable in you case

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame as df
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

origin_data = np.array([
    [0.0000000, 0.0287198],
    [0.0100000, 0.0655187],
    [0.0200000, 0.0665948],
    [0.0300000, 0.0676697],
    [0.0400000, 0.0797021],
    [0.0500000, 0.0883750],
    [0.0600000, 0.0824649],
    [0.0700000, 0.0726798],
    [0.0800000, 0.0749663],
    [0.0900000, 0.0746549],
    [0.1000000, 0.0767466],
    [0.1100000, 0.1051620],
    [0.1200000, 0.0846607],
    [0.1300000, 0.0746683],
    [0.1400000, 0.0744862],
    [0.1500000, 0.0913541],
    [0.1600000, 0.0844304],
    [0.1700000, 0.0750595],
    [0.1800000, 0.0783450],
    [0.1900000, 0.0869718],
    [0.2000000, 0.0969575],
    [0.2100000, 0.0924280],
    [0.2200000, 0.0759971],
    [0.2300000, 0.0704025],
    ])

n = origin_data.shape[0]
data = df(origin_data, columns=['x', 'y'])

window = 6

roll_avg = data.rolling(window).mean()
roll_avg_cumulative = data['y'].cumsum()/np.arange(1, 25)

avg = data['y'].mean()
std_error = data['y'].std()

print('{:.2f} +/- {:.2f}'.format(avg, std_error))

# all data
plt.plot(data['x'], data['y'], c='b')

# rolling avg by "window"
plt.plot(roll_avg['x'], roll_avg['y'], c='r')

# cumulative avg
plt.plot(data['x'], roll_avg_cumulative, c='orange')

# horizontal line at overall avg
plt.hlines(avg, data['x'].iloc[0], data['x'].iloc[-1],
           ls='--',
           colors=['k'])

# ymax - ymin band
plt.fill_between(data['x'], avg+std_error, avg-std_error, alpha=0.5)
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT, THANKS, and a thousand and one THANKS, dear Joao_PS

Frankly, I am very happy and lucky
Thank you very much dear Joao_PS

Comment: I ran and the result is: 0.08 +/- 0.01

Comment: I hope everyone enjoys the script of Joao_PS

Comment: Dear Joao_PS, in case the result (origin_data) is a file.csv file what should I do to read my .csv file
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
origin_data = np.array(df)

Comment: @al ahmed, the `origin_data` refers to the data you provided above... I only used this data and so the result is 0.08 +/- 0.01... For your script, don't use `origin_data`. Just use pandas to read the csv file and assign that to the `data` variable: `data = pd.read_csv('file.csv')`.

Comment: Thank you dear @Joao_PS, and sorry for my late reply.
I'm going to try.

Comment: I can't get the desired results.
I'm going to ask this question (new question on stackoverflow) putting your script. I hope you will agree.

Comment: I asked the question right now
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74215211/read-csv-file-plot-the-running-average-and-calculate-average-value-%c2%b1-using-py